# Google Places API: Less results if filtering by more types (and vice versa)

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

My applications shows nearby places by using the Google Places *Web* API.

The user has control over the place types searched in the requests.
Multiple types are concatenated with the pipe symbol `|`. I use `&rankby=distance`, because prominence does not matter for the app.

I have noticed, that requesting nearby places with "a lot" of types returns less results than filtering by a single type.

**Example**

- returns 10 results near where I live:

  `&types=airport|bank|bar|bicycle_store|book_store|bus_station|casino|cafe|city_hall|clothing_store|food|furniture_store|grocery_or_supermarket|gym|hardware_store|library|liquor_store|movie_theater|museum|night_club|park|place_of_worship|police|post_office|restaurant|school|shoe_store|shopping_mall|spa|stadium|store|subway_station|train_station|university|zoo`
- returns 20 results and a `next_page_token` (so at least 20 results):

  `&types=store`

I happen to live across a shopping mall, so I know for sure that there are more than 20 stores nearby. The first query contains `store` as a filter, too.

**Questions**

I would like to always show as many results as possible. Has anybody experienced the same issue? Is there any document that I did not see, anything on this topic?

I'm a bit lost, since I don't know where to start looking or how to approach this problem.

Comment: Note that the "types" parameter on NearbySearch is deprecated (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#deprecation)

Comment: @AndrewR thanks andrew! The german version of the docs never mentioned anything like this. But after switching the language to english I can see the deprecation warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AndrewR 's comment, I stumbled upon a comment on an issue, that states the following:

> [Google Places API does not] support specifying more than 20 types at a time
>
> – [Comment on bug report from Sep 1, 2014](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35824841#comment4)

which solves my problem in a few words. I wish the docs had stated this.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that searching for more than one type at a time is deprecated. See http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2016/02/changes-and-quality-improvements-in_16.html:

> Beginning Feb 16, 2016, we are replacing the types restriction
>   parameter with a new type search parameter. If you have been using the
>   types parameter for Nearby Search, Text Search or Radar Search you
>   will be affected.
>
> Type search works similarly to types restriction, but it only supports
>   one type per request.
>
> Requests using the types parameter and those specifying multiple types
>   (for example, types=hospital|pharmacy|doctor) will continue to return
>   results until Feb 16, 2017, but we do not recommend using multiple
>   types in a search request. After that date, requests with multiple
>   types will no longer be supported. To ensure the best possible search
>   results for your users, we recommend using a single type in search
>   requests.